# Extract Use Case's Keywords from Python

Tags: enterprise-architect

From Python via win32com I extract all Use Cases from my Enterprise Architect project:

```
use_cases = EA.GetElementSet("select * from t_object where Object_Type='UseCase'", 2);
```

By looping on `use_cases`, I want to get the Use Case's "Keywords".
By trying to call e.g. uc.pdata5 I get an attribute error.

How to get it?

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining what do you need, what have you tried so far, and why it isn't working as expected (i.e.: error messages, etc.). Also consider taking the time to format your question to be easily understood by readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PData5`is the field in the database where this information is stored.

However if you get the use cases via the API you have elements of type `EA.Element` which are documented in the [manual](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/element2.html)

In this case you would need to use `uc.Tag`. From the manual:

> Tag
>
> String
>
> Notes: Read/Write Corresponds to the Keywords field in the Enterprise Architect user interface.

Comment: Isn't MiscData what corresponds to Pdata? 0-indexed, so in this case MiscData(4)?

Comment: Yes, but in this case I suspect (haven't tested) that you can use both. I would prefer to use `Tag` rather then `MiscData(4)`

Comment: Geert is right.
Both solutions, uc.miscdata(4) and uc.tag, do what required.
Thanks guys.

Comment: In that case you may mark my answer as accepted to indicate that this problem has been solved.